# Syncronize ui file with cpp on Qt

Tags: qt, layout

I am writing a simple app using Qt. My project contains an `ui` file because it is easier to change layouts.

Well, sometimes I just edit `cpp` file to add something new. But the `ui` file does not show it.

For example, in `cpp` I use

```
QWidget *logo = new QWidget(this);
    logo->setStyleSheet("background-color: red");
    logo->setGeometry(QRect(50,50,500,110));
```

but when I open  `ui` file within Design mode, this new red rectangle is not there.

How to update the layout on `ui` file?

Comment: It does **not** work like that. Whatever you add in the designer gets added into the `.ui` file. Now, when you build your project, [uic](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/uic.html) reads the `.ui` file and creates a c++ header file out of it (usually named `"ui_*.h"` and included in the widget's class cpp file). This header file has the definition of the function `ui->setupUi(this);` which is called at the beginning of your widget's constructor by default. The point is, anything you do after this function call, has nothing to do with the designer.

Comment: @Mike, thanks for such well explained answer. It makes lot of things clear now.